# What port should i forward for raspberry pi web server?

Tags: webserver, raspberry-pi

I want to host a website from my raspberry pi and I was wondering what port I should use?

Comment: 80 would make most sense, if it's available, since it's the default so you don't need to worry about port numbers in your URLs.

Answer (score 0):

The most logical answer would be `port 80` for http, or if you wish to be more secure, `port 443` for https.

Comment: Does this answer your question? If so,please accept the answer.